# Checking if certain key exists in database

Tags: ssas, ssas-2008, adomd.net

I have saved certain MDX query and I run them using ADOMD.NET. I get CellSet back which I convert into dataset. All this is working fine. Now the DB team has changed the cube structure. They have updated the DimesnionName, Attribute Name etc. Some dimensions got renamed and some got deleted. Becuase of this I am unable to run my saved queries. I want to create a console application, which will take list of keys ([DimensionName].[AttributeName] or [DimensionName].[AttributeName].[MemeberName] format) and it will tell me following keys does not exists.

Please let me know if this is possible programatically. I dont want to check it manually.

Kindly share a link or code which will help me acheive this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ADOMD already this should be no problem, just use the metadata queries:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123485.aspx

Alternatively, AMO is nice http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.analysisservices.aspx

I use it in SSIS for processing, you could easily use it in .Net to test existence of elements:

```
using Microsoft.AnalysisServices;

...

Server server = new Server();
server.Connect(cubeConnectionString);
Database database = server.Databases.FindByName(databaseName);
Cube cube = database.Cubes.FindByName(cubeName);


foreach (MeasureGroup measureGroup in cube.MeasureGroups)           
{
  foreach (Partition partition in measureGroup.Partitions)
  {
  ...
  }
}

foreach (CubeDimension cubeDimension in cube.Dimensions)
{
  Dimension dimension = cubeDimension.Dimension;
  var dimName = dimension.Name;
  ...
}
```

Finding the names in advance for all the elements you need is probably the hard part (And keeping it all up-to-date).

Would it not be easier to fire all the queries at the cube and try to trap the "no such thing" response?